# Open external website in new tab when user click fancybox IMG

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

Have setup Fancybox to popup to first time visitors. Fancybox contains a image and i want link in that image. So when user clicks it a new tab with the href opens.

```
    <div id="usplayers" class="fancybox" style="max-width:500px;overflow:none;display: inline- block;">
    <a href="External URL" target="_blank">
        <img src="/folder/img.gif"> </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popit() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#usplayers").trigger('click');
        }, 2000);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var visited = $.cookie('hello');
        if (visited == 'yes') {
            nothing();
        } else {
            popit();
        }
        $.cookie('hello', 'yes', {
            expires: 15
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not working with the external link, Only way to open it somehow is to click mouse scroll.

Comment: You aren't closing your img tag inside the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to `wrap` the opened image in fancybox inside an anchor tag `<a>` that will target the external URL.

First you have to build your html properly in order to bind fancybox like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="{the image that you want to open in fancybox}">
  <img src="{the thumnail that users see on your page}" alt="" />
</a>
```

... if the visitors click on your thumbnail, fancybox will display the image you targeted in the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag (this will be also fired by your `popit()` function).

Then you will need to use a fancybox callback to `wrap` the opened image an another `<a>` tag that will open the external URL in a new tab .... so your code should look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popit() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#usplayers").trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    var visited = $.cookie('hello');
    if (visited == 'yes') {
        // nothing(); // this is not defined
        return false; // use this instead
    } else {
        popit();
    }
    $.cookie('hello', 'yes', {
        expires: 15
    });
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // here you wrap the opened image
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-image").wrap("<a href='http://jsfiddle.net' target='_blank' />");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CXuyu/)**

**EDIT** :

Based on @blachawk 's comment, if you have more than one element to display in fancybox and each element should link to a different external URL, you could dynamically pass each URL using a (HTML5) `data-*` attribute like :

```
<a id="usplayers" data-url="jsfiddle.net" title="fire fancybox" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

... then, within the same callback, fetch the `data-url` attribute's value and set the `href` of the wrapping `<a>` tag like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        var url = "http://" + $(this.element).data("url");
        $(".fancybox-image").wrap("<a href='"+url+"' target='_blank' />");
    }
});
```

Of course, see updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CXuyu/1/)**

Comment: very nice comeback and explanation.  This should work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<a href="External URL" target="_blank">
<img   src="/folder/img.gif" </a>
```

To:

```
<a href="External URL" target="_blank">
    <img src="/folder/img.gif" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: That was just a typo by me, It's not the problem / solution

Comment: The typo *could* have stopped it from working. If this didn't fix it, could you elaborate on how it isn't working? Are there any console errors?

Comment: No errors, It just won't open the url except if i do a mouse wheel click ( Open link in new tab )

Comment: Sounds to me like somewhere in your code the click function is calling `preventDefault()`. This will prevent the link from behaving as it normally would.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with fancyBox. The code was built to pop up an image in a popup window on top of the page you are on, not open a new tab to display info about the image you just opened.

Comment: Yeah that was what i started to understand, But would not a way around that be to emulate a mouse wheel click ?

Comment: Disagree ... you either didn't understand the question or don't know too much about fancybox ;)

Comment: See my answer, which includes jsfiddle

Comment: hmm - that is still a tough solution because you initially hardcoded the link.  Mathias will have to write a logical function build on top of the fancybox package to get what he wants.  OOTB, what he is asking for is not naturally provided, which is why I said what I said. But it doesn't mean it can't be done - it just means that this package may not be the best solution for what he is trying to do.  But good attempt at it JFK!

Comment: is true, I hard-coded the URL but you can always pass it from the clicked element using a `data` attribute ... I will edit my answer. thanks for the input.